# Deleted password from keychain access now I can't access my server even with RSA keys

Tags: keychain, ssh

By mistake, I deleted my server keychain passwords and even with the private key on `.ssh`. I can't access it because it is asking for a password I never wrote down.

Is there a way:

1. To revert what I deleted
2. To be able to access the server in any other way
   this is how I access it `ssh -p 12345 -l root xx.xxx.xx.xx -i ~/.ssh/username`
   but it keeps on asking for that password

Comment: Do you have a recent backup?

Comment: Usually you need the Public key to connect to a remote server. Also, which password is it asking for: the passphrase of the key or the password of the server account?

Comment: @SolarMike, no unfortunately I do not have a backup of the server

Comment: @nohillside I am almost sure I did the RSA key with a password and since the password was in the keychain now I don't have it anymore

Comment: Did you use `rm` to delete the keychain passwords from the command line or another method?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: @mr.cook I was removing older servers logins and passes from keychain and deleted it simply

Comment: Probably the only way to regain access to your server is boot into the recovery partition to either add a new admin account or to archive and reinstall. If you have access to the server, it's the cheap solution, if not, then you have to pay the hosting or colocation service for their "hot hands" work. Once you have access to the server, you can look for remnants of the deleted files. (Next time make a backup admin account; also make regular, multiple backups.)